# starting activity on uncaughtException() call

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, android-intent

I want to start a new activity from my `UncaughtExceptionHandler` when an uncaught exception appears. Is this possible?

I think the current activity can't start a new child activity in its "error" state because I always get this errors:

```
07-14 14:34:06.075: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=de.rwth/system.ErrorHandler (has extras) }
07-14 14:34:06.615: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4338f8d8 de.rwth/.main}
07-14 14:34:16.115: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-14 14:34:16.628: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{433a89d8 de.rwth/system.ErrorHandler}
```

I tried to start the child activity from a new thread, because i thought the current thread might be in a state where it is not allowed to start a new activity but this didn't work too.

So does anyone know how this could work? 
How do i prevent the current activity from blocking everything while in this error state? is the any way to set the exception to handled?

Comment: Launching an application from an `ExceptionHandler` is wrong.

Comment: What if we just want to present the user to email the exception output. How so?

Comment: I want to display a new activity (or anything else i can set a layout to) with the errorlog so how can i do this? the default error handler does show a error message to so it must be possible. maybe the problem is that the new activity is a subactivity from the current (broken) activity and wont display because of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you will need to do is specify your exception display `Activity` in your manifest file and set `android:taskAffinity` and `android:process` to values different from your main process. Then you'll need to specify an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) and use that to start the activity and pass the data.

By default the taskAffinity is inheried from the main `<application>` tag and is the same page name set in the `<manifest>` tag. You probably want something like `android:taskAffinity="org.example.package.TASK.ExceptionDisplay"`

By default everything in one `<application>` tag runs in the same process. You can change that using the `android:process` attribute you probably want something like `android:process=":exception_process"`.

Check out this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more details.

Comment: what do i have to set android:taskAffinity and android:process to? I understand the part with the intent filter but i dont know what these two parameters do.. my intent filter works for the calling intent and looks like this:

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:mimeType="activity/errorReport" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>

Comment: this is really great, seems like it works now :) thanks a lot. i had an other question in the meanwhile about remote services ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269176/activity-crashes-when-remote-service-crashes ). it seems that you know this part of android very well, maybe you know the answer to this too;) services dont have a affinity attribute and im not shure how to seperate them from the calling activity