# Start activity from UncaughtExceptionHandler()

Tags: android, exception, process, android-activity, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Every time I catch exception I handle it on my base activity (extends Application) and than I want to start back my LoginActivity witch is Launcher activity.
changes made so far :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
});
```

Due to information get from [starting activity on uncaughtException() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246530/starting-activity-on-uncaughtexception-call) I added this to LoginActivity to start it

```
android:process=":login_exception_process"
```

Problem that all global / static veriables that were assign in LoginActivity  - are NULL in other activities ! 
So how can I make this veriables global for all processes ?

Comment: show the code of your AsyncTask and LoginActivity. And why do you use separate process every time to relaunch LoginActivity?

Comment: Edited. What do you mean by "And why do you use separate process every time to relaunch LoginActivity?"